# AttributeError 'function' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: graph, deep-learning, neural-network, model, knowledge-graph

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-693d5c02ad4f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 A = grid_Graph(28, k=8)
      2 plt.imshow(A.todense())

<ipython-input-33-5baca42f7d47> in grid_Graph(m, k, corners)
      3     To create adjacency matrix as per Defferrard et al. 2016
      4     '''
----> 5     z = Graph.grid(m)
      6     dist, idx = Graph.distance_sklearn_metrics(z, k=k, metric='euclidean')
      7     A = Graph.adjacency(dist, idx)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

The code I'm trying to develop a Graph Convolutional Neural Network. I have defined the grid_Graph and trying to develop the metrics. Error is coming after the last line. How to develop the metrics:

```
def grid_Graph(m, k=8, corners=False):
    '''
    To create adjacency matrix as per Defferrard et al. 2016
    '''
    z = Graph.grid(m)
    dist, idx = Graph.distance_sklearn_metrics(z, k=k, metric='euclidean')
    A = Graph.adjacency(dist, idx)

    # Connections are only vertical or horizontal on the grid.
    # Corner vertices are connected to 2 neightbors only.
    if corners:
        import scipy.sparse
        A = A.toarray()
        A[A < A.max()/1.5] = 0
        A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
        print('{} edges'.format(A.nnz))

    print("{} > {} edges".format(A.nnz//2, k*m**2//2))
    return A
```

def draw_graph(A, m=28, ax=None, spring_layout=False, size_factor=10):
'''Draw the graph given adjacency matrix(A),
optionally with spring_layout.
'''
assert m**2 == A.shape[0] == A.shape[1]
# Create the nx.Graph object
G = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(A)
print('Number of nodes: %d; Number of edges: %d' % 
(G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges()))
grid_coords = Graph.grid(m)

```
if spring_layout:
    # remove nodes without edges
    nodes_without_edges = [n for n, k in  G.degree() if k == 0]
    G.remove_nodes_from(nodes_without_edges)
    print('After removing nodes without edges:')
    print('Number of nodes: %d; Number of edges: %d' % \
          (G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges()))

z = Graph.grid(m)

# initial positions
pos = {n: z[n] for n in G.nodes()} 

if spring_layout:
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, 
                           pos=pos,
                           iterations=200)

ax = nx.draw(G, pos,
             node_size=[G.degree(n) * size_factor for n in G.nodes()],
             ax=ax
            )
return ax
   
    A = grid_Graph(28, k=8)
    plt.imshow(A.todense())
```